# Computing the length of period

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I want to show that the length of the period of the following product is 2:

$P(x) =\pi x \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1- \frac{x^2}{n^2})$.

I my textbook I found this equation of partial products:

$P_N(x) =\pi x \prod_{n=1}^{N} (1- \frac{x^2}{n^2}) = \frac{(-1)^N \pi}{N!^2} (x-N) (x-N+1) \cdots (x+N-1)(x+N)$

$\Rightarrow \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{P_N(x+2)}{P_N(x)} = 1$

I can not figure out how to compute this representation/equation of the partial products, and I neither know why we can draw this conclusion about the limits. Can someone help me there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write

$$\left(1 - \frac{x^2}{n^2}\right) = \frac{n^2-x^2}{n^2} = \frac{(n-x)(n+x)}{n^2} = \frac{(-1)(x-n)(x+n)}{n^2},$$

then collect the signs to get the $(-1)^N$, and the denominators to get $(N!)^2$ in the overall denominator. Then you rearrange the remaining products in the numerator,

$$\begin{align}
x\prod_{n=1}^N (x-n)(x+n) &= \prod_{k=-N}^{-1}(x+k)\cdot x \cdot \prod_{k=1}^N(x+k)\\
&= (x-N)(x-(N-1))\cdot \dotsc \cdot (x-1)\cdot x\cdot (x+1)\cdot \dotsc \cdot (x+N-1)(x+N).
\end{align}$$

Then you read off

$$\frac{P_N(x+2)}{P_N(x)} = \frac{(x+N+1)(x+N+2)}{(x-N)(x-N+1)}\xrightarrow{N\to\infty} 1$$

for all $x\notin\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel Fischer gave a brilliant answer to your question. Then, just for you curiosity, I shall just mention that $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1- \frac{x^2}{n^2})=\frac{\sin (\pi  x)}{\pi  x}$$ which is of the beautiful identities I learned when young (so long time ago !)

Comment: Indeed, that was the equation I had to compute first and I got it for x $\in$ [-1,1], but then I had this problem to show  it for all x ;)